How to show column based on the certain radio button value selected
our company just upgraded our Classic SharePoint to 2016 and currently I'm working on the SharePoint workflow for approval. I have 2 questions?
1.) Post upgrade, I noticed all of the scripts that embedded in our site is NOT working as asual. For example all the field hide and bold using Script Editor is Not Working.
2.) I tried to hide column as per below code and basically more likely the same as what I did in the form from previous version. I have no idea, where I did wrong. Can anyone assist on this matter?
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sdlc/SiteAssets/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/sdlc/SiteAssets/sputility.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
$('{44f672d5-f430-4275-93e8-d044b239bd32}').change(function(){ //Using RadioButtonID
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$('{fd2f2adf-0a92-4869-83fa-aeafd5e8e92c}').closest('tr').hide();   // Hide input field if checkbox is checked
console.log("Project Approval is Mandatory Deliverables" );
} else {
$('{fd2f2adf-0a92-4869-83fa-aeafd5e8e92c}').closest('tr').show();   // Show input field if checkbox is unchecked
}
});
});
</script>


How the migration was done? By backup/restore content databases or with a tool like ShareGate? The GUID of site columns (eg. 44f672d5-f430-4275-93e8-d044b239bd32) have probably changed.

@jleture it was done by SharePoint Team and our team just their users. How the GUID of the site columns impact the simple code as mentioned above because the GUID is as per latest UI? Any suggestion?

The question was not by "who" but "how". This piece of code is terrible and probably relies on internal GUID that could be changed during the migration depending the tool or procedure used for the migration.
